# Load mySQL Data Into Form

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am using the PHP and AJAX coding below to populate a map showing various markers for a given location stored in a mySQL database.

The markers are correctly shown but what I would like to be able to do is to populate the fields on my form with the associated data from the database, so that as each marker is clicked the fields will show the data pertient to that marker.

**PHP Code**

```
<
?php 
require("phpfile.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node 

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); 
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); 
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server 

$connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table 

$query = "SELECT findid, locationid, findosgb36lat, findosgb36lon, dateoftrip, findcategory, findname, finddescription, pasref, findimage, additionalcomments FROM finds WHERE `locationid` = '2'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each 

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE 
$node = $dom->createElement("marker"); 
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findid",$row['findid']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("locationid",$row['locationid']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findosgb36lat",$row['findosgb36lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("findosgb36lon",$row['findosgb36lon']);
$newnode->setAttribute("dateoftrip",$row['dateoftrip']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findcategory",$row['findcategory']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findname",$row['findname']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("finddescription",$row['finddescription']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("pasref",$row['pasref']);
$newnode->setAttribute("findimage",$row['findimage']);
$newnode->setAttribute("additionalcomments",$row['additionalcomments']);

} 

echo $dom->saveXML(); 

?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Finds Per Location</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/findsperlocationstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            Artefact: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Coin: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Jewellery: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            // Creating a LatLngBounds object
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:14, 
            mapTypeId: 'satellite' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var findid = markers[i].getAttribute("findid");
            var locationid = markers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
            var dateoftrip = markers[i].getAttribute("dateoftrip");
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");
            var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");
            var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
            var pasref = markers[i].getAttribute("pasref");
            var findimage= markers[i].getAttribute("findimage");
            var additionalcomments= markers[i].getAttribute("additionalcomments");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: 'Click to view details',
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
            bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
</head> 
            <body onLoad="load()">
            <form name="findsperlocation" id="findsperlocation">
              <p align="left"><label>Location id<br />
              </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid" value="2" readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left"><label>Date of Trip<br />
              </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="dateoftrip" type="text" id="dateoftrip" readonly="readonly"/>
              </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left">
                <label></label>
                <label>Find Category</label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="findcategory" type="text" id="findcategory" size="10"readonly="readonly"/>
              </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left">
                <label>Find Name</label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="findname" type="text" id="findname" size="35" readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left"><label>Find Description</label>&nbsp;</p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="finddescription" type="text" id="finddescription" size="100"readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
              </div>
                <p align="left">
                <label>
                <label>PAS Ref.  </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="pasref" type="text" id="pasref" readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left"><label>Additional Comments</label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <textarea name="additionalcomments" cols="50" rows="12" id="additionalcomments" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left"><br />  
                </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left"></div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
</html>
```

I think I'm half way there because I'm mangaing to pull all of the information from the database. I can see this when I run the php script in my web browser, but I'm just not sure what to do for the next step.

What do I need to do next?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Finds Per Location</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/findsperlocationstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            Artefact: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Coin: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Jewellery: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            // Creating a LatLngBounds object
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:14, 
            mapTypeId: 'satellite' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var findid = markers[i].getAttribute("findid");
            var locationid = markers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
            var dateoftrip = markers[i].getAttribute("dateoftrip");
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");
            var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");
            var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
            var detectorname = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorname");
            var searchheadname = markers[i].getAttribute("searchheadname");
            var detectorsettings = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorsettings");
            var pasref = markers[i].getAttribute("pasref");
            var findimage= markers[i].getAttribute("findimage");
            var additionalcomments= markers[i].getAttribute("additionalcomments");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: 'Click to view details',
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow,
            formdateoftrip: "dateoftrip",
            formfindcategory: "findcategory"
            }); 
            bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {   alert("Associated data: " + this.formdateoftrip + ", " + this.findcategory); }); 
            }); 
            } 


            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 

</head> 
            <body onLoad="load()">
            <form name="findsperlocation" id="findsperlocation">
              <p align="left"><label>Location id<br />
              </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid" value="2" readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left"><label>Date of Trip<br />
              </label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="dateoftrip" type="text" id="dateoftrip" readonly="readonly"/>
              </div>
              </div>
              <p align="left">
                <label></label>
                <label>Find Category</label>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div align="left">
                  <input name="findcategory" type="text" id="findcategory" size="10"readonly="readonly"/>
              </div>
              </div>

              </form>
            <div id="map"></div>
            </script>
            </body> 
</html>
```

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
map: map, 
position: point, 
title: 'Click to view details', 
icon: icon.icon, 
shadow: icon.shadow, 
formdateoftrip: "dateoftrip", 
formfindcategory: "findcategory",
formfindname: "findname",
formfinddescription: "finddescription",
formpasref: "pasref",
formfindimage: "findimage",
formadditionalcomments: "additionalcomments"
}); 
bounds.extend(point); 
map.fitBounds(bounds); 
} 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {  
document.getElementById('dateoftrip').value = this.formdateoftrip;
document.getElementById('findcategory').value = this.formfindcategory; 
document.getElementById('findname').value = this.formfindname
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store additional data in your marker just by adding new fields like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{          
  map : map, 
  position : point,
  title : 'Click to view details',
  icon : icon.icon,
  shadow : icon.shadow,
  myVariable1 : "some data from xml",
  myVariable2 : "some other data"
});
```

Then all you have to do is register onClick event for the marker and put it's data into the form.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()
{
  alert("Associated data: " + this.myVariable1 + ", " + myVariable2);
});
```

// Edit:

Obviously the code above only shows how to retrieve data from the marker - it was just an example. Putting your data from JavaScript into the form is a 2 step process. The first thing you have to do is to give every  field you want to fill an unique id via "id" attribute. You've already done it. Then all you have to do is put following code in the onClick event (instead of alert() in the sample above):

```
document.getElementById('formdateoftrip').value = this.formdateoftrip;
// repeat it for other fields here
```

Good luck ;)

// Another edit:

I didn't notice you've put google.maps.event.addListener in wrong place. The reason it works for only one marker is you've put it outside your "for" loop which creates the markers. It has to be inside, right after the "map.fitBounds(bounds);" but before "}", so move it one line up.

The second problem lies in passing the data in the marker. If you want to reference variables, you can't put them in quotes. You use quotes to write strings.

Replace:

```
formdateoftrip: "dateoftrip", 
formfindcategory: "findcategory",
...
```

Into:

```
formdateoftrip: dateoftrip, 
formfindcategory: findcategory,
// fix the others below too
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I've done what you suggested, but I'm sorry I'm a little unsure about the latter part where you explain about adding the data into the form. I've posted the updated code in my original query. I get the 'on click' event to happen but rather than the data showing in the form I receive a message dialog box with the information. Apologies you can maybe tell that I'm fairly new to this. Could you perhaps please point me in the direction as to how I put the data in to the form fields. Many thanks and kind regards Chris

Comment: It was just an example how to retrieve data from marker, I've assumed you can handle the rest :) Anyway I've edited my post above to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I feel really stupid here. I understand the coding that you've kindly shown above, and I've implemented three fields just to get me started. However, there are two markers correctly shown on my map, but the 'on click' event only works for one marker and when I've clicked on it, instead of the correct data being shown it just shows the field name. I am very sorry to keep bothering you with this, but could you perhaps highlight where I'm going wrong with this please. I've included a snippet of the code above. Many thanks, once again. Regards. Chris

Comment: Hi, many thanks for bearing with me on this and for the clarification. I've got some of this working, i.e. only certain fields are showing the data that has been saved. I'll have a closer look at this and let you know how I get on. Once again sincere thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Sebastian, just wanted to drop you a quick note to say that I have got the whole form working now, thanks to you. I just wanted to say many thanks for your time an trouble it is greatly appreciated. Kind regards Chris.